# How to customize context menu in Windows 8 for all running tasks

Tags: windows-8

I am missing some of (perhaps all) system tasks that used to be available in context menus of the previous Windows versions. Please see the attached image for details. 
Is there a way to make, say, "Move" easily available (so that I can, e.g., move a window from invisible part of display within a remote session)? How?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use **shift + right click** (eightforums.com)